# Cannot get data with AngularJS + Azure WCF

Tags: json, angularjs, wcf, azure

I'm trying to get data from my website using AngularJS to my wcf in Azure but i'm getting error.
In my js:

```
$http({
url: dataService.serverPath + 'Services.svc/Login',
method: 'GET',
 headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    'Accept-Charset': "charset=utf-8",
                },
                params: { key: key }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //some code here
                }
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.hasError = true;
                $scope.errorMsg = "The request failed: " + data;
            });
```

fiddler response:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 22:17:09 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

49
{"ID":0,"NomeUsuario":"Admin","IsAdmin":true,"Error":null}
0
```

Note, i'm getting HTTP 200 and i'm getting error. 
The return data is `49 { Json } 0`, what is it?
I tried to remove the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` from my WCF but no success.

I spend this hole day trying getting data from Azure and i didnt. Running on my dev machine, it's fine and does not show Transfer-Encoding : Chuncked nor the 49 and 0 enclosure my JSON.

Answer (score 0):

first thing that came to my mind was the MIME type as it needs to be changed by FTPing to your Website in Azure and updating the WebConfig file. But this usually returns 404 as in your case it returns 200, still no harm to check.

My other suggestion would be about the WebInvoke inside your WCF (if you are using it) following piece should set your WCF for Json usage.

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Your template here",
     Method = "GET", 
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebmessageFormat.Json, 
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried put WebInvoke on my wcf service but still doesn't work.